# How to perform Multiple If statement inside Case statement of SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I want to create multiple if else statement inside the case of sql server.
Is it possible then please provide me one example.
In c# you can write the multi line statement inside the case.

Is it possible in SQL Server like C# switch case.

I want to put below code in case  loop

```
IF @SegmentId > 0 and @AttributeName IS NOT NULL   
begin
  select AttributeID,Attribute_key from AttributeMaster 
  where AttributeTypeId =@AttributeType and SegmentId=@SegmentId 
  and Attribute_key   like '%'+@AttributeName+'%' order by AttributeID
end

else IF @SegmentId = 0 and NULLIF(@AttributeName, '') IS NULL   
begin
  select AttributeID,Attribute_key from AttributeMaster 
  where AttributeTypeId =@AttributeType  order by AttributeID
end

else IF @SegmentId > 0 and NULLIF(@AttributeName, '') IS NULL   
begin
  select AttributeID,Attribute_key from AttributeMaster 
  where AttributeTypeId =@AttributeType and SegmentId=@SegmentId  
  order by AttributeID
end
```

I need to implement the `@AttributeTypeId` is 1 then different condition. `my@AttributeId` from `1 to 5`

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Can you provide your question in preudo-code snippet.

Comment: [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)? Did you look at the `BEGIN/END` keywords?

Comment: I have to implement one switch case type of condition in sql server. Just simple query is it possible in case I can perform other if condition varification.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for Tsql `CASE` and how it works;

```
--(1) Simple case
case X when 1 then 'X is 1' 
       when 2 then 'X is 2' ...
       else 'X is not 1 or 2' end as colName

--(2) Searched case
case when X < 1 then 'X is less than 1' 
     when X = 1 then 'X is 1' ...
     else 'X is greater than 1' end as colName
```

I think your whole thing can be put `into a single query`;

```
select AttributeID, Attribute_key 
       --uncomment next line if needed   
       --,case AttributeID when 1 then 'A' when 2 then 'B' ... end 
from  AttributeMaster
where AttributeTypeId =@AttributeType and 
      SegmentId= isnull(nullif(@SegmentId,0),SegmentId) and
      Attribute_key like 
           case when  @SegmentId > 0 and @AttributeName is not null 
           then '%'+@AttributeName+'%' else Attribute_key end
      --uncomment if filter needed
      --and AttributeID <6
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do all your if/else  conditions mentioned in your question using sql query below

```
select AttributeID,Attribute_key from AttributeMaster 
where AttributeTypeId =@AttributeType 
and (@segmentId = 0 or SegmentId=@SegmentId)
and (NULLIF(@AttributeName, '') IS NULL OR 
         Attribute_key   like '%'+@AttributeName+'%') 
order by AttributeID
```